# brew install gradle をするもcurl: (56) LibreSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 54となりインストール出来ない

Tags: gradle, homebrew

GradleをインストールしたくHomebrewを利用しbrew install gradleをすると下記のようになりインストール出来ません。

```
~ $ brew install gradle
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 2 taps (homebrew/core and homebrew/cask).
==> New Formulae
kde-kdoctools
==> Updated Formulae
balena-cli      epubcheck       gatsby-cli      jc              pdftk-java
citus           erlang@22       graphene        neon            pnpm
cpr             fpc             guile           nest            tnftpd
diamond         freerdp         harfbuzz        okteto          tokei
==> Deleted Formulae
marathon-swift
==> Updated Casks
balenaetcher        gpodder             powerpanel          ticktick
boxcryptor          mmex                stellarium          ximalaya
google-chrome       mps                 stremio

==> Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
==> Downloading from https://downloads.gradle-dn.com/distributions/gradle-6.5-al
                                                                           0.6%
curl: (56) LibreSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 54
Error: Failed to download resource "gradle"
Download failed: https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
~ $
```

調べたところ「curl: (56) LibreSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 54」というのがバッファの容量の問題と考えられ、「brew cleanup」をしキャッシュの削除をしましたが上記内容は変わりませんでした。
その他、考えられる原因がわからず手詰まりです。ご教授お願い致します。

```
~ $ openssl version -a
LibreSSL 2.8.3
built on: date not available
platform: information not available
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(16x,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) blowfish(idx) 
compiler: information not available
OPENSSLDIR: "/private/etc/ssl"
~ $ brew -v
Homebrew 2.4.1
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 0204; last commit 2020-06-22)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision 575fd; last commit 2020-06-23)
~ $ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.15.5
BuildVersion:   19F101
~ $
```

Comment: 追記丁寧にありがとうございます！　このエラーは僕も OpenSSL で経験したことがあって、そのときはリトライで直ったのでおそらくネットワーク速度か何かが不調だったのだと思います。ですが今回はおそらくリトライしても直らないということですよね。うーむ……。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。昨日と今日と何度かリトライしているのですが、ダウンロード進まず上記の結果になってしまいます。。。

Comment: WiFiの2.4GHz→5GHzに変更したらダウンロード 出来ました。お騒がせしました。

Comment: おお！　良かったです  もしよければ、[自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)としてご投稿願えませんでしょうか？　暫く待てば自分の回答を承認することもできるようになります :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WiFiの2.4GHz→5GHzに変更したらダウンロード 出来ました。

Answer (score 3):

ネットの接続性が悪い場合になります（私の経験でも、公衆 Wi-Fi で混雑しているような場面でなったことがあります）。おそらく応答速度が遅いと、正常なデータを得られなかったと判断され、SSL のエラーとして報告されますが、実際は SSL の処理自体に問題があるわけではありません。

たとえ Wi-Fi が 2.4GHz であったとしても、通信が安定している限り、問題はないはずです。2.4GHz か 5GHz かどうかは、本質的に問題の原因としては関係がないでしょう。@tk32 さんの通信環境では、5GHz の方が 2.4GHz のように帯域が混雑しておらず、接続が安定していた、というだけのことのはずです。